# setNamedRange in Google apps script using a cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So, I'm new to this, but I am capable of copying code & adapting it for simple things. I want to use the contents of cells to create the names in Named Ranges.
In A1 I have the name I want to use and in A2:A22 I have the range of data.

Someone shared this, which works nicely to setNamedRange if the name of the named ranged is explicit in the script - TestRange as per the code:

```
function testNamedRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('here is the spreadsheet id');
  var range = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A2:A22');
  ss.setNamedRange('TestRange', range);
  var rangeCheck = ss.getRangeByName('TestRange');
  var rangeCheckName = rangeCheck.getA1Notation();
}
```

but if I substitute the name 'TestRange' with say 'Sheet1!A1' it won't take the text from Sheet1!A1 and use it for the name of that range - error message "The name given to this range is invalid.":

```
function testNamedRange() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('here is the spreadsheet id');
  var range = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A2:A22');
  ss.setNamedRange('**Sheet1!A1**', range);
  var rangeCheck = ss.getRangeByName('**Sheet1!A1**');
  var rangeCheckName = rangeCheck.getA1Notation();
}
```

Comment: You have the right idea, but with programming (vs formula crafting) you need to be explicit. Note how the code accesses the Spreadsheet, Sheet, and Range classes. Two of the methods associated with a Range allow accessing the value of its cell / cells. You can find these on the Apps Script documentation (from the Help menu).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a method that gets the cell, then another to get its value.

i.e.

```
var cell = ss.getRange('Sheet1!A1');
var cellValue = cell.getValue();
```

For further details please checkout https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets